# How can I append a new result column showing the result of the WHERE clause for that row?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Instead of retrieving only the rows satisfying the WHERE clause, I intend to have a new result table column shows the result of that WHERE clause. For instance;

```
ColA   ColB   ColC   NewCol
xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   1       # where clause is true for that row
xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   0       # false for that row
xxxx    xxx    xxx   0
....
```

How can I design such a query in MySQL?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example, I'm a little unsure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CASE statement to achieve what you are after:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MyField = Whatever THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NewCol
FROM.....
```

Leave out the WHERE clause all together.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL treats booleans as 0 if false and 1 if true.

So, the easiest way to do what you want is:

```
select t.*,
       (<where clause>) as NewCol
from table t;
```

Comment: Is there a reason for this downvote?  Or is it just malicious?

Comment: user is asking the same that how can he put where clause as column, and instead of guiding him of syntax you are telling him the same that put your where clause as column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, 
(CASE WHEN ColA = Whatever THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS WhereColumnResult)
FROM myTable
```